# Fan Wiring: Black vs red wire

Tags: wiring

My contractor removed multiple ceiling fans and I am replacing them with new fans.   There is a red, black (hot) and white (neutral) wire.   Is it normal for only the red wire to have 120V AC?  An AC meter reads 18V across the black and white wires: 120V AC across the red.

## Updates

Good questions are appreciated. Updates will be edited here to respond to good diagnostic questions:

- This non-standard wiring was observed in 3+ fixtures
- Each fixture is controlled with a single switch
- All fans for this discussion are ceiling fans
- Black to white AC potential is 18V
- I believe that I have not mistaken green for black

Current configuration: Wired and powered new fans with **Red** wire and is controlled by a switch in the wall

It is puzzling that the Black-White potential is anything other than 120V

Comment: Is the black on a switch?

Comment: Are you sure the black is black and not a very dark green? I've seen some wire where the green is so dark it almost looks like black in certain lighting.

Comment: What kind of fan do you have: ceiling fan, sports fan, duct fan, ...?

Comment: Can you look inside the switch box for that black wire?

Comment: You might take apart a switch and see if the other end of the blacks is in there capped off,. Sounds like /3 wire since there is a red.  This would have been used with a light and fan with a dual controller such as https://m.grainger.com/product/5PWK3&AL!2966!3!166589569630!!!g!104635268757!?s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166589569630!!!!104635268757!&ef_id=VHpXWwAABFmE34mM:20170825000625:s 18v is just floating - it's not real add a light bulb in the circuit and it will be 0v

Comment: Did you resolve this? Take voltage readings between all wires with the switch off and again with the switch on. Post these in an edit to your question. Also post any pictures you have taken of the boxes.

Comment: @ArchonOSX  Yes, I had to connect an AC multi-meter to measure potentials with the swtich on and then off.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the red wire is to control the attached light via a switch.

[Try the link below for more info.](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/install-ceiling-fan-black-white-red-green-wires-49026.html)

Comment: I red the same article when wiring.  There is only one single switch per outlet